# Heavy sap weeping at base of stone fruit tree

Tags: sap

Location: Phoenix, AZ

I have a 3-in-1 pluot that was grafted onto Citation Hybrid root stock. (i.e. the image shows the root stock.) Around 2 months ago (~ 1st July) it started weeping sap at the base of the trunk and this is becoming worse.

What could be causing this? Is there a way to fix/stop this?

[image]

Comment: Been over-wet, or over dry? Water stress can do this, so can fungal infections in a wet year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unfortunate that this is happening at the base of the tree - its called Gummosis or sometimes Canker and is very common on stone fruits. Often, the gummosis leads to a bacterial infection which can be quite offensive smelling, and at that point, it is described as bacterial canker. The link below will give more information, but the eventual outcome for a tree with this problem so low on the main trunk is often death. There isn't much you can do about it now I'm afraid.

http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/gardens-gardening/your-garden/help-for-the-home-gardener/advice-tips-resources/pests-and-problems/diseases/cankers/gummosis-of-fruit-trees.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Where do you live?  Do you have freezing during the winter?  This is probably a totally normal response that happens on the SOUTH side of trees.  The south side gets the sun and experiences free/thaw.  Any wounds at all will gum.  Ummm, this must be a cherry, fruit...??  Didn't look it up. Grins!

No problem unless gets infected.  The gumming helps STOP infection as well as insects from getting in the cambium.  If I were you I'd pull that dang bark stuff away from the bark.  Make sure that no bark is under the soil or mulch!  That will kill your tree!  Roots are underground, bark is in the air!!  So pull back that bark (get rid of chunky bark!!  ugh!), leave gummosus alone and not to worry.

At least find a fine textured mulch (best if human poo mixed with sawdust and completely, COMPLETELY decomposed...BEAUTIFUL stuff...mulch should not be so coarse as to detract from the beauty of plants...tougher for decomposers to decompose to be able to feed your soil...blah, blah, blah...)  (get rid of that awful mulch...this stuff is made from construction materials and called...shoot, can't remember at the moment!  Awful stuff...awful.  Does not inhibit weeds...doesn't feed your soil and looks...well...awful!  Grin, ignore me if you like the look!!) Please tell me there is no landscape fabric or plastic beneath!!  If there is...welp.  Ask another question about it and I'll be jumping in with both feet!!

Comment: The first line of the question: Location: Phoenix, AZ